# add an input in a div with javascript

Tags: javascript, input, django-templates

i have in my html page this div shown as lightbox:

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="text" id="user_1" name="user_1" value="user_1"/><br>
    <input type="text" id="user_2" name="user_2" value="user_2"/><br>
    <input type="text" id="user_3" name="user_3" value="user_3"/><br>
    <label onclick="add_input();"><img alt="add_other" src="add.png"></label>
</div>
```

and i want when i click on the image the input will be added and appeared, i tried to do that with the following Js function :

```
function add_input(){
        var div = document.getElementById('container');
        var input = '<input style="width:300px;" type="text" id="user" name="user" value=""/>'
        div.innerHTML+= input;
    }
```

the div with `id="container"` has in its css `height : auto` and after clicking on the add image an input appear but outside the lightbox.
is there an other way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're putting the input inside the container, so it just sounds like a CSS issue. Perhaps an ancestor element is limiting the height.

WRT your function, don't use `.innerHTML += "<input...>"`

This is destructive, and can be especially bad with input elements.

Instead create DOM elements using creation methods:

```
function add_input(){
    var input = document.createElement("input")
    input.style="width:300px;" 
    input.id = input.name = "user";
    document.getElementById('container').appendChild(input);
}
```

---

Or if you're absolutely set on using HTML markup, at least insert it in a way that doesn't destroy and rebuild the existing content.

You can do this with `.insertAdjacentHTML()`

```
function add_input(){
    var div = document.getElementById('container');
    var input = '<input style="width:300px;" type="text" id="user" name="user" value=""/>'
    div.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", input);
}
```

You'll just need a shim for old Firefox.

Comment: even with `.innerHTML += "<input...>"` it works, the problem was in a div superior of div container that was generated with an js file has a fixed height

Comment: @Drwhite: Yes, I know `.innerHTML += ...` seems to work. I'm saying don't do it. It's a bad practice in most cases and will cause you problems later, especially with input elements.